# Prevent Toast on handled exceptions ACRA

Tags: android, error-handling, acra

i am using ACRA for error reporting and everything seems to be fine.
i want to send report of handled exceptions as well so i am using

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(e);
```

but **don't** want the Toast to appear on the **handled exceptions**. but want toast on **unhandled** exceptions! so is there any way to specify this condition?

EDIT

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
        reportType= HttpSender.Type.JSON,
        formUri = MFRestConstants.CREATE_ACRA_REPORT,
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.msg_toast_text,
        additionalSharedPreferences={"MutterflyAppPref"}
)
```

Comment: u must be declaring @ReportCrashes() in your app, what do you write inside it ?

Comment: updated qus with ReportCrashes check @varunkr

Comment: i want toast to be displayed when its unhandled exception. so mentioned the toast in ReportCrashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method called  [handleSilentException](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage).

Usage: `ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(e);`

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used ACRA before but it is obvious that your mode is set to

```
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST
```

This should display a Toast shouldn't it?

You should simply remove that line because you don't want to notify the user I guess !!

Comment: thanks dude! i want to display toast on Unhandled exceptions(and so added the line in ReportCrashes) but not on handled exceptions! that's the catch.
by handled exceptions i mean the one for i have added try catch block

Comment: "Handled" exceptions are not caught by ACRA.